# The solution of a second order nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I am trying to derive the solution for following second-order nonlinear ODE

$$ 2f(x)f''(x)=f'(x)^2 .$$

The solution for this ODE I obtained from software is

$$f(x)=\frac{c_1^2 x^2}{4c_2}+c_1 x+c_2 .$$

Plug it into the ODE, and the equation hold. However, it's obvious that $x^2$ is also a possible solution for the ODE, and we could find that if we want the $x$ term and the constant term to vanish, we need to set $c_1 =c_2 =0$, but then the $\frac{c_1^2}{4c_2}$ is undetermined. My question is, how to derive  $\lim\limits_{c_1 \to 0,c_2 \to 0}\frac{c_1^2}{4c_2}=1$ in this case?

Comment: @JohnB just the independent variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking derivatives on both sides gives
$$
2f'f''+2ff'''=2f'f''
$$
and so $ff'''=0$. Therefore, $f'''=0$ (this also holds when $f=0$). So you can replace
$$
f(x)=c_0x^2+c_1x+c_2
$$
in the original equation to get
$$
2(c_0x^2+c_1x+c_2)2c_0=(2c_0x+c_1)^2.
$$
After a few computation you will find all possible values of $c_0,c_1,c_2$, namely $c_1^2 = 4 c_0 c_2$.

For example, for $c_1=c_2=0$ and $c_1=1$ we get $f(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
2f(x)f''(x)=f'(x)^2 &\implies 2\frac{f''}{f'}=\frac{f'}{f} \\
&\implies 2\ln{f'}=\ln{f} + c_1 \\
&\implies f'=c_1f^{1/2} \\
&\implies 2f^{1/2}=c_1x+c_2 \\
&\implies f(x)=(c_1x+c_2)^2
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\dfrac{c_1^2 x^2}{4c_2}+c_1 x+c_2 .$$
Simply rewrite this as:
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{4c_2}(c_1^2x^2+4c_1c_2 x+4c^2_2)$$
$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{4c_2}(c_1x+2c_2)^2$$
$$f(x)=\left(\dfrac {c_1x}{2\sqrt {c_2}}+ {\sqrt {c_2}}\right)^2$$
Note that since $f=ax^2$ is a solution the ratio $\dfrac {c_1}{2\sqrt {c_2}}$ can be any number $\in \mathbb{R}$ (not only $1$). It can also be zero since $f=0$ is also a solution of the DE.
$$f(x)=(αx+β)^2$$